# How to get an xml to display as an rss in IE 8?

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-8, rss, browser

I feel like I might have a misunderstanding of how rss feeds are written/tested/generated. I know most people probably use automated services to create rss feeds. But I just wanted to test this one out. I have this sample xml file that I have validated here:
 http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>XML Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>
    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

My understanding is that rss feeds are just xml files so I am making the assumption that there is a way to view the xml as a formatted rss page in IE 8 but it keeps displaying the xml text:

[image: WhatISee]

I am using an older browser - IE 8 - but I have also tried the newest version of Firefox.

I was expecting to see something like this:

[image: WhatIWantToSee]

Is there a way to get IE or another browser to recognize that the xml file should be displayed as an rss feed? Thanks.

**Addition:**
Feed reading view is turned on in my internet options as well - that does not seem to be my issue.

Comment: Reading more: It appears web browsers have built in xslt(or xsl?) stylesheets that display the rss/atom xml files in a more human friendly format. The question is how do I get it to do this to my xml file above.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is what you are generating: XML.

To change the format on a client, you can use an XSLT file that you reference in your RSS file like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/rss.xsl"?>
```

The rss.xsl file will then transform the XML for display in a browser and generally be ignored by RSS readers.

In most cases that line appears right after the `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/rss.xsl"?>
<rss version="2.0">
...
</rss>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for taking a crack at this old question. I have an xml file that I want to display as a feed - the same way other feeds are displayed in ie 8. I don't want to give it my own format - I just want it to have it "be" an rss feed in ie 8. I link to it from a separate html file like this: <span class="buttonText" id="nav2"><a href="rssfeed.xml">testrssfeed</a></span>

Comment: You may try to retrieve an RSS file that works and see what they use. For example, the wget tool can be used to retrieve a file and make sure the browser doesn't parse it in any way. Once you have that file, look at the format, maybe they have some form of xml-stylesheet name that triggers something special in IE.